# Django form field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I want to pass the screen size of the client to the django view.py. Right now I am trying to pass it through a form from jQuery, but I keep getting 'None'. What am I doing wrong? Or is there any other way I could get the screen size?

My js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('{{ form.width.id_for_label }}').value = screen.width;
   document.getElementById('{{ form.height.id_for_label }}').value = screen.height;
</script>
```

imput.html:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.myfield }}
    <div class='width'> {{ form.width }} </div>
    <div class='height'> {{ form.height }} </div>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" style="display: none"/>
</form>
```

form.py

```
class MymodelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ['myfield', 'width', 'height',]
        widgets = {
            'width': forms.HiddenInput,
            'height': forms.HiddenInput
        }
```

view.py

```
def make_image(user_input, img_w, img_h):
    bg = Image.new('L', (img_w, img_h), "WHITE")
    obj_img = Image.open(path + '/project/static/' + user_input + '.png')
    rand = randint(1, min(bg.size[0], bg.size[1]))
    obj_img = obj_img.resize((rand,rand))
    bg.paste(obj_img)
    img_io = BytesIO()
    bg.save(img_io, format='PNG')
    img_content = ContentFile(img_io.getvalue())

    return img_content

def get_input(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MymodelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            img_w = form.cleaned_data['width']
            img_h = form.cleaned_data['height']
            img_content = make_image(form.cleaned_data['myfield'], img_w, img_h)
            img = form.save()
            img.image.save(str(img.pk)+'.png', img_content)
            img.save()
            return redirect('output_image', pk=img.pk)
    else:
        form = MymodelForm()
    return render(request, 'project/input.html', {'form': form})
```

So what I basically want to do is to get the user screen size so I could generate an image that takes up the fullscreen of users in view.py.

Comment: You can get the screen size of client by using [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) module in python.

Comment: Share the code for the view that you are referring to as well. That info is necessary here

Comment: Hey, thanks So I just updated my post with view.py. I also tried pyautogui but when I tried to deploy it via pythonanywhere, it says that GUI cannot work in server side environment..? So I assumed I might have to use jQuery instead.

Comment: Make sure your script tag is somewhere below your form inputs or are executed after document has been loaded, they might not be finding the element because its not loaded yet.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for your insight. Though it is beyond the form input and I also added window load right before my function but its still not working..